# Xalan-Java: Set search path

Tags: xslt, xalan

I've written a stylesheet that loads a second stylesheet and overrides a few things. Trouble is, to use the `xsl:import` element, I seem to need to know the absolute path to the stylesheet I'm trying to import. How can I get around this?

Ideally I don't want to put the absolute path into the stylesheet. I want to pass it in on the command-line. That way, if the base stylesheet moves, I don't have to go edit *all* of my stylesheets.

I'm using the command-line Xalan-Java tool to apply XSLT. A had a look at the manual, but there doesn't seem to be any kind of a "look *here* for stylesheets" kind of option.

I also thought about passing the base path in as an XSL parameter - but I don't see how I can shove that into the `href` attribute of the `xsl:import` element...

Any hints? Surely I can't be the first person ever to want to do this...

---

Basically I'm writing documents using DocBook. I've downloaded a copy of the official DocBook XSL stylesheets (which are *huge*, and consist of thousands of XSL files). For each document I write, I want to make a tiny XSL file which imports the official DocBook XSL, and then tweaks a few settings (paper size, etc.)

In order to do that, it appears that I would have to hard-code the path to the official DocBook XSL file into each document's local XSL. And *that* means that if I ever update to a newer version of the official stylesheets, I'll have to go edit every custom XSL I've ever written [because the stylesheet version number is in the pathname].

What I would *like* to do is hard-code that path into the script that runs Xalan. So if the stylesheets ever move, I can just edit one script, and it's done. But I can't figure out how to do that. I can't see any way to tell Xalan where to look for imported stylesheets.

Even if I use relative paths, those paths still have a version number hard-coded into them. And Windows can't do symlinks, so...

Answer (score 0):

The href attribute can be a relative path; so long as the base URI is known.

If you're running from the command line then the base URI of the "master" stylesheet is generally known, so this shouldn't be a problem. I think you need to be more specific about what you are doing and how it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

OK, well I found *a* solution:

Write one XSL file with the absolute path to the official DocBook stylesheets hard-coded into it. Have all the custom stylesheets import from that one. (Apparently you can do that.)

Now if the official stylesheets ever move, I only have to edit one file.

(This does still mean that I need to be able to find the magic stylesheet. Putting it in the folder above where I keep all my documents makes this a simple relative path operation.)